# How do I use a .SSK file to add a theme/skin to my C# form/application?

Tags: c#, skin

So anyways, I got a program recently called "SkinBuilder Tool". More specifically "SkinBuilder for Sunisoft Skin Solutions v2".

It can open bitmaps and their own type of "skin" file (file extension is .ssk).

It then "builds" the theme/skin into something that is allegedly applicable to a C# forum, however, when I click build, it just tries to save it as another skin file (.ssk).

So, how do I:
1) Save it to something other than a .SSK that is applicable to my form?

2) Use the .SSK on my form to apply the skin/theme?

Comment: You should ask the author of the program for such support.

Comment: This seams like a tech support question for "Sunisoft".

Answer (score 0):

When you setup SuniSoft IrisSkin you find an extra control in the control box of visual studio with the name "SkinEngine".

When you use this controls in your application, it affects all forms in this application.

You should choose the .ssk file from the skinfile property of the control, If You used Trial version or Unregistered copy of software then please register first.